# How do I get org-mode heading faces in helm

Tags: org-mode, helm, faces

When using commands like `helm-in-buffer-headings`, it would be much more readable to see output styled (and ideally even indented) like it is in the original document. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your emacs packages and it should work!

Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly what did it, but I just updated a number of packages, including `helm` and `org`, and now headings are colored and formatted in a very helpful way (same font face as an org buffer).

My current versions are:

- `helm`: 20150706.633
- `org`: 20150706

If you know the exact cause, feel free to edit this answer, or write a new one and I'll accept it instead. But regardless I hope this is helpful for those who face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[worf-goto](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf) can do this, with fontified and indented headings, as well as named blocks:

[image: screenshot]

But I actually prefer the more generic and flexible
[swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), see
[screenshot](https://oremacs.com/download/org-mode-swiper.png), since
it goes through the whole buffer, not just the headings. With the
right query, there's only a few more matches then when looking at just
the headings.  But it works for everything, so if the thing that you
are looking for isn't in a heading, you can see that immediately.

Comment: These are some great suggestions, so I already upvoted. However, I'm not sure if this actually helps if I want to keep using helm? I see there is swiper-helm, which is nice, but I don't think it quite solves the problem. This did help me realize though that my motivating question is actually the more general "How do I keep the 'standard' faces when using helm for everything?" I could change the question, but I don't know if that's appropriate since your answer may be less relevant then, unless you also want to change it.

Comment: worf-goto uses helm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! These are both great packages though it ended up not being the best way for me to solve this personally. I might use `swiper-helm` though to replace `helm-swoop` though!